# How to stop a repeating-linear-gradient in CSS?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, repeating-linear-gradient

In order to add a `repeating-linear-gradient` in CSS one can do this with something like the following code. It will create a nice div-element with horizontal bars.

```css
.gradient {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, green, green 10px, #ffffff 10px, #ffffff 20px);
}

div {
  width: 390px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

The challenge however is to have this repeating gradient stop/end half way through the element. The last half of this element should not display the gradient. How can this be achieved?

A possible solution would be to use `linear-gradient` instead and hard-code all your needed bars. But given the rather large amount of code you would have to write for this solution this is not desirable.

Other searches on the internet did not review how this could be done for this specific use case. With the help of [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient()) for example, one can lookup how `repeating-linear-gradient` works. But since it does not provide an example for this situation, I do not know the best approach for this problem.

Comment: `background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, green, green 10px, #ffffff 10px, #ffffff 20px) left/50% 100% no-repeat`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for sharing. Very elegant and concise. This would be an excellent solution you could add as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the gradient size and disable the repetition:

```css
.gradient {
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, green 0 10px, #ffffff 0 20px)
    left  / 50%   100% no-repeat;
/*position / width height */
}

div {
  width: 390px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: [will try to find the duplicate later]

Comment: How is your search going? I have done an extensive search on Stackoverflow and the internet and I came to the conclusion this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

After some amount of fiddling around I came to the following solution, where I introduce a `linear-gradient` on top of the `repeating-linear-gradient`, giving the illusion that the gradient had stopped. This works by having the first part of this `linear-gradient` be completely transparent by setting the last value of `rgba` to `0.0`.

```css
.gradient {
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 50%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%),
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, green, green 10px, #ffffff 10px, #ffffff 20px);
}

div {
  width: 390px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Inspiration for this answer came from [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46297750/background-in-css-with-linear-gradient-and-repeating-linear-gradient) and I have modified the code for this specific purpose.

Comment: I advise you to have a look and background-size and background-position. This is what you need to use here. Not another gradient on the top

Comment: That is a much more elegant solution! Thanks, I was looking for such a thing!